# Redis nopass while creating a container in docker

Tags: redis, environment-variables

I want to deploy a redis container in docker / podman where I need to use "nopass" as environment variable in single command, nopass in mentioned in redis.conf, however, I have no idea how to implement in single docker command, please help

I tried

docker run -d --name redis2  -e REDIS_PASSWORD=passwd  --nopass $REDIS_PASSWORD redis redis-server

as well as

docker run --name redis -d redis redis-server --nopass

However,  container goes in exit status with error as REDIS_PASSWORD not set

or

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 7.0.11) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 2

> > > 'nopass'
> > > Bad directive or wrong number of arguments